# как написать условие , отслеживающее нажатие картинки/ кнопки в python(pygame )?

Tags: python, pycharm, pygame

```
place = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1 and place[0] >= button_exit_x and place[0] <= indificator_button_exit_x and place[1] >= button_exit_y and place[1] <= indificator_button_exit_y:
```

Comment: https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_14/adding_play_button/button.py

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать button в модуле pygame?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496162/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-button-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5-pygame) (вернее не возможный, а точный)

Comment: Я привёл довольно простой код, вот более функциональный код: https://github.com/nchistov/pyne/blob/master/pyne/widgets/button.py

Comment: А ещё есть целый проект н github про это: https://github.com/FrCln/pygame-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Можно, так:

```
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
```

где rect это ограничивающий картинку прямоугольник `rect = img.get_rect()`. [Работа с изображениями.](https://pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3_image/image.html)

Comment: код не работает ни в какой форме, запутился кое как но потом просто тне реагрировал на кнопку